# Console error when pressing run | Discord.js Axios for webhook

Tags: javascript, axios, discord.js

I made a code where I would send the football games and update the score for each goal and penalties, but when I press "run" it stops alone and there is no error in the console, I have already tried to do this with console.log and it does not work came to nothing! Does anyone know what the error could be?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { WebhookClient, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

console.log("Teste iniciado");

const apiKey = process.env['API_KEY'];
const leagues = [
  {
    id: '2002',
    name: 'Bundesliga',
    thumbnail: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/f/f9/Bundesliga_logo_%282017%29.png'
  }
];

async function getLiveScore(league) {
  console.log("Função getLiveScore iniciada");
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.football-data.org/v4/competitions/${league.id}/matches`,
      {
        headers: {
          'X-Auth-Token': apiKey,
        }
      }).catch(function(error) {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
          console.log(error.response.status);
          console.log(error.response.headers);
        }
      });

    console.log("Resposta da API obtida com sucesso");

    const liveMatches = response.data.matches.filter(match => match.status === 'LIVE')

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle(`Placar ao vivo - ${league.name}`)
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .setThumbnail(league.thumbnail);

    liveMatches.forEach(match => {
      let score = `${match.score.fullTime.homeTeam} x ${match.score.fullTime.awayTeam}`;
      if (match.score.penalties) {
        score += `\nPênaltis: ${match.score.penalties.homeTeam} x ${match.score.penalties.awayTeam}`;
      }
      embed.addFields(`${match.homeTeam.name} x ${match.awayTeam.name}`, `${score}`, true);

      if (match.score.goalsHomeTeam) {
        match.score.goalsHomeTeam.forEach(goal => {
          embed.addFields(`${match.homeTeam.name} gol`, `${goal.minute} - ${goal.scorer.name}`, true);
        });
      }
    });

    console.log("Função getLiveScore concluída com sucesso");
    return embed;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
let resultado;
let esperado;
if (resultado === esperado) {
  console.log("resultado esperado obtido");
} else {
  console.error("resultado não é o esperado:", resultado);
}
module.exports = async (res) => {
  console.log("Função principal iniciada");
  const discordWebhookUrl = process.env['WEBHOOK_URL'];

  const client = new WebhookClient({ url: discordWebhookUrl });

  const promises = leagues.map(league => getLiveScore(league));
  const liveScores = await Promise.all(promises);

  liveScores.forEach(liveScore => {
    client.send({ embeds: [liveScore] });
  });

  res.status(200).send('Live scores sent.');

};
```

I put a console.log solution to report the error, if you want to know the API, it's football.data.org

Comment: What do you mean by _"it stops alone"_? Are you sure there are games where the `match.status` is `'IN_PLAY'`? Also, there is no `embed.addField` in discord.js v14. It's `embed.addFields` now.

Comment: I changed `match.status` to `'SCHEDULED'`, where all future events will be taken, I also changed it to `embed.addFields` when I say that it stops alone, it's because I press run on the console and it stops without no console error